# Parse Date Column using Regex / Perl

Tags: regex, perl, date

I am writing a perl script to parse tab delimited data from standard input.

The script removes leading and trailing whitespace, blanks out any field that has the string "NULL" and re-formats date columns from "MMM DD YYYY HH:MM:SS:SSSAM" format to "YYYYMMDD" format.

Sample Input:

```
93092   Apr  1 2010 12:00:00:000AM      59668370.60702875
22341   Apr  1 2010 12:00:00:000AM      51309196.84639429
27844   Apr  1 2010 12:00:00:000AM      NULL
150465  Apr 22 2010 12:00:00:000AM      19706190.97586569
119364  Jul  20 2010 12:00:00:000AM      16335977.41009162
```

Target Output:

```
93092|20100401|59668370.60702875
22341|20100401|51309196.84639429
27844|20100401|
150465|20100422|19706190.97586569
119364|20100720|16335977.41009162
```

The script takes an argument representing the column(s) which have dates that need conversion.  In the sample above, I would invoke with "1" as the param, since the 2nd column is the date that needs conversion.  More than one column would be represented by a comma separated list.

This is what I've been able to do so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @date_cols = split(/,/, $ARGV[0]);

while (<STDIN>) {
   my @fields = split(/\t/, $_, -1);
   for (@fields) {
      s/^\s+//;
      s/\s+\z//;
      s/^NULL\z//;
   }
   for (@fields[@date_cols]) {
##NEED HELP WITH DATE FORMATTING
   }

   print(join('|', @fields), "\n");
}
```

Comment: Is your file tab-delimited? Otherwise, your second column (going by whitespace) is just the month, not the entire date.

Comment: I'd recommend using a module like [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime::Format::Strptime) to handle the details of this. Formatting a date from a [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime) object becomes trivial at that point.

Comment: Or perhaps Time::Piece - which is in the Perl core distribution.

Comment: I don't have admin on this machine, so I need to use something that's in the standard distribution.  I've never used a module (like Time::Piece) before which I why I was hoping to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) is simple and easily provides you with the date formmating.  The `strptime` function lets you define the pattern you want to work with; the `strftime` function lets you produce the output format desired.  Consider:

```
use Time::Piece;
my $date = "Apr  1 2012 12:00:00AM";
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S%p");
print $t->strftime("%Y%m%d\n");
```

A nice feature of this approach is that it doesn't matter whether one or two spaces separate the month and day fields; the results are the same.

Comment: The date format includes additional :000 in the seconds.  I was able to change your example to include ":000" in the strptime function.  `my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:000%p");`  This part works now.  I tried to plug this into the original script and I'm getting an error "Error parsing time at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Time/Piece.pm line 470, <STDIN> line 1."   `for (@fields[@date_cols]) {
        my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($_,"%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S:000%p");
        my $s = $t->strftime("%Y%m%d\n");
        splice(@fields,@date_cols,1,$s);
   }`

Comment: Actually... this worked well. I found a type-o that was causing my problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Dave Cross's suggestion above to use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece):

```
use Time::Piece;

while (<STDIN>) {
    # Split each row into columns by white space
    my @fields = split /\s+/;

    # Rebuild the date ("Apr 1 2010") from columns 2 through 4
    my $time_field = join ' ', @fields[1..3];

    # Parse the date - see man strptime
    my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($time_field, '%B %d %Y');

    # Format the output - see man strftime
    print join '|', $fields[0], $date->strftime('%Y%m%d'), $fields[5];
}
```

Regex is a really excellent tool, but dates are ugly (horrifying even). Whenever possible I prefer to use libraries that already exist for parsing them.

Comment: I'm not sure if parsing on white space is the best option here since there could be multiple date fields within the input file and the math to figure out which columns represent a date will get complicated quickly.